# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 al querer correr una consulta desde una pagina WEB

Tags: c#, sql-server, aplicación-web, visual-studio-2013

Saludos.

He estado investigando sobre el siguiente error que me aparece al momento de correr una pagina web que estoy programando en VS2013

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
>
> Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se
>   establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el
>   servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la
>   instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir
>   conexiones remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 -
>   Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificado)

Entre las respuestas e información que he encontrado me dice que revise los servicios de SQL, las conexiones (TCP/IP & Named pipelines), el connectionString.

De todo eso:
*Los servicios estan corriendo (incluyendo el SQL Browser)
*Los servicios de las dos instancias que tengo estan corriendo
*Las conexiones TCP/IP estan habilitadas y con el puerto 1433 configurado
*El connection string lo he declarado de las siguientes formas

```
<add name="ServProd" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.54.86\\TR; Initial Catalog=db; User ID=sa; Password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="ServProd" connectionString="Data Source=ambientePROD\\TR; Initial Catalog=db; User ID=sa; Password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

y de ninguna de las dos formas ha funcionado.

Ël firewall esta configurado para permitir las conexiones. Incluso paginas y aplicaciones anteriores no tienen problemas para conectarse a las bases de ese servidor, pero este desarrollo en especifico esta teniendo este problema.

¿Algun detalle que me haya saltado revisar en código o configuración?

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Haz probado quitando la doble barra \\\?
Quedando así.
<code>
Data Source=192.168.54.86\TR;
</code>

Comment: @GuillermoOjedaAyala si, y sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, incluso hay equipos en mi red que funcionan y otros que no, ellos se conectan a la base mediante aplicacion de escritorio WINFORM con C#.

Comment: Tenía el mismo error y al agregar el puerto en el string de conexión se resolvió el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy 99% seguro que no tienes configurado SQL Server para acceso externo:

En SQL Management Studio das click derecho en tu servidor, seleccionas propiedades y te vas a conexiones y luego marcas la opción de permitir conexiones remotas al servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparte, abres el SQL Server Configuration Manager, expandes el nodo SQL Server Network Configuration y seleccionas la opción "Protocols for MSSQLServer" (o como se llame tu instancia) y asegurate que TCP/IP esté habilitado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ambos campos estan configurados como lo muestras. De hecho ese servidor lo usamos con los demas aplicativos de la empresa y no tenemos ningún problema. Pero con este desarrollo en especifico esta brincando esto del error 26

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta el puerto, prueba así:

```
<add name="ServProd" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.54.86\TR,1433; Initial Catalog=db; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Ya hice la prueba, el error cambia por el siguiente:

El equipo remoto rechazó la conexión de red

Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta a ver prueba así

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo error. Tanto si uso la ip del servidor, como el nombre

Comment: ¿Le agregaste Persist Security Info=True; ?

Comment: Si, le inclui el Persist

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, 
Create un fichero .bat en el servidor y pega dentro esto.

```
@echo =========  SQL Server Ports  ===================
@echo Enabling SQLServer default instance port 1433
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLServer"
@echo Enabling Dedicated Admin Connection port 1434
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1434 "SQL Admin Connection"
@echo Enabling conventional SQL Server Service Broker port 4022
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 4022 "SQL Service Broker"
@echo Enabling Transact-SQL Debugger/RPC port 135
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 135 "SQL Debugger/RPC"
@echo =========  Analysis Services Ports  ==============
@echo Enabling SSAS Default Instance port 2383
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2383 "Analysis Services"
@echo Enabling SQL Server Browser Service port 2382
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2382 "SQL Browser"
@echo =========  Misc Applications  ==============
@echo Enabling HTTP port 80
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 80 "HTTP"
@echo Enabling SSL port 443
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 443 "SSL"
@echo Enabling port for SQL Server Browser Service's 'Browse' Button
netsh firewall set portopening UDP 1434 "SQL Browser"
@echo Allowing multicast broadcast response on UDP (Browser Service Enumerations OK)
netsh firewall set multicastbroadcastresponse ENABLE
```

Eso abre todos los puertos que tienen que ver con el sql server.
Ejecútalo y nos dices.